# read/write SLE4442 memory card with WinSCard API in c#

Tags: c#

#### A bit of background information:

Inorder to read/write to SLE4442 memory cards, my app is currently using an Omnikey Cardman 3021 USB card reader, a Sumbsembly Smartcard API (external dll) which is capable of wrapping CT-API calls (directed to omnikey's dll) so that I can read/write the memory card in my c# app.
The only problem here is that Omnikey only provides a 32-bit dll of their CT-API. I asked if they are going to produce a 64-bit version, but they couldn't be bothered.

#### Current situation:

Inorder to make my application 64-bit capable, I must rewrite it using Windows WinSCard API. The problem here is that there are no specific examples on the web how to do it. Also getting hold of working APDU commands is nearly impossible, but I've managed to aquire two slightly different versions that sort of work.
I have googled this a hundred times over many months and with what I have managed to gobble together I can finally read the SLE4442 memory card. But for the life of me I can't get writing to work.

#### The code:

I'm not going to post the entire code into this first post (if need be I can do it later or provide a link to the source code).
But I'll outline the basic steps.

1) SCardEstablishContext

2) Get the reader name via SCardListReaders

3) SCardConnect

4) Read entire memory with SCardTransmit and APDU new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xB0, 0, 0, 0 };

5) Verify pin with SCardTransmit and APDU new byte[] { 0xFF, 0x20, 0, 0, 3, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF }; (Note that this does return 0x90;0x00 as a response, which means the verification should have been succesful)

6) Try to write with ScardTransmit and APDU new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD6, 0, 0, 50, 1 }; (try to write value 1 at memory position 50) - I have also tried using an APDU with the first parameter being 0x00 and/or the second byte being 0xD0. The response has never been 0x90;0x00 so I assume there is an error during writing, but I haven't been able to find any meaning to the error codes returned.

#### Possible causes:

Because I can read a memory card with the WinSCard API then it must be possible to also write to one (side note - the memory card(s) that I try to write to are in in working condition, I haven't locked them down by failing to verify the PIN 3 times).

1) Maybe the write APDU command is wrong. Could be that the instruction byte (second byte) is incorrect, or the memory location uses some sort of an extended coding scheme.

2) Maybe the verify command didn't actually verify. As in the command itself is fine, which is why 0x90 was returned, but I must call or setup something first.

3) Just a hunch, but I think that this is the real culprit. While googling I did find some vague references to having to call the SCardControl method with parameter IOCTL_SMARTCARD_SET_CARD_TYPE and setting the card type to SLE4442. But again no working examples anywhere and my trial-and-error testing resulted in failures. I got "One or more of the supplied parameters could not be properly interpreted." and some other error messages as well, can't remember what they all were. Assuming the code I copy-pasted from google code has the right descriptions for the error codes.

#### What I need:

What I need is someone to post or direct me to a site that has full+working code in c# for read/write SLE4442 using WinSCard API and it must work in both 32-bit and 64-bit enviroments.
The code doesn't have to be foolproof - eg. handling every possible error situation nicely. I should be able to do that myself. But if it is (including the APDU command result descriptions - eg. 0x90;0x00 is success, but 0x6B;0x4D is... etc...) then all the better.

Comment: Hi , I want to get start working with this device in C# , Would you please send me link or any other information ?

Comment: @shaahin - what do you mean under device? The Omnikey Synchronous API (finally 64-bit as well) with documentation is available on www.omnikey.com...

Comment: Thanks, Is that support in Windows 7 64 bit ?

Comment: @shaahin - yes, Win 7 64-bit is supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APDU for writing to card, in your example, should be:

```
FF D6 00 50 01 01
```

Comment: Just tried the APDU you provided and I get Error Code 31 ("undocumented error", according to some google code) from SCardTransmit itself.

If I remove "0x" from the last three numbers the result is the same.

If I mess about with the first two parameters (like I did in section "The code:" entry number 6.) then the call to SCardTransmit succeeds, but the returned result is either 110 or 109 (byte value), not 144 (0x90) like it should be.

And predictably, because of the errors, the memory position 50 hasn't been updated...

Comment: Could you provide a portion of the code where you prepare params for the SCardTransmit and the function call? 
Before writing to the card you must verify a PIN (0xFF, 0x20,... part) and then 0xFF, 0xD6, ... part.
Here is the structure of the writing APDU:
CLA=0xFF
INS=0xD6
P1=0
P2=0x50
P3=1
DataIn=1

Comment: I do verify the PIN before I write, and the verification does seem to return an OK result - 0x90;0x00.
Because the comment section can't contain code nor long text I decided to take a snapshot of the code in question. You can look at it here: http://mommi.planet.ee/muu/code.jpg

Comment: I've checked your code and (although I'm a Delphi programmer) it seems to be OK. 
Error code 31 (0x1F) means ERROR_GEN_FAILURE - A device attached to the system is not functioning. So if you have a chance to try this code on another reader, give it a go.

Comment: Sadly Omnikey is the only choice of card readers we have here and even if there were others available it's too late to start replacing them now. So I have to get it working with an Omnikey card reader. The reader and the memorycard are otherwise fine, because I can write to the card with my app. Thus I probably need to initialize the card reader differently, most likely with IOCTL_SMARTCARD_SET_CARD_TYPE...

Answer (score 2):

Our Omnikey (3121) terminal writes data on SLE4442/SLE4442 cards perfectly, try this APDU:
FF D6 00 04 10 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E AA
see also: 
http://acs.com.hk/drivers/eng/API_ACR122U.pdf, chapter 5.4

Comment: I tried your code with my Omnikey 1021 (I had to give my 3021 away a while back) and I got error code 31 - Undocumented error again. But your text got me thinking, so I tried out your code via remote desktop on a machine with Omnikey 3021 and it worked! I always figured that the 1021 was a cheaper - worse build quality - version of the 3021, but it seems the driver support differs as well. I'd like to accept your answer as well, but stackoverlow allows only one answer, so I'll give it to Johnny since he answered first. Now my only problem is getting the code to work with the 1021 as well...

Comment: Hi Marko, 

Sure Johnny may have those points; now I have a question:
I can verify the PIN (PSC) e.g. FF 20 00 00 03 FF FF FF
but I cannot change the PIN e.g. FF 24 00 00 06 FF FF FF 01 02 03 returns 6D00
Can you help?

Best regards,
Albert
info@loyaltygroup.nl

Comment: By the way, I'll get the Omnikey 1021 tomorrow from my colleague and will do some tests. Note that we buy the Omnikey 3021 for only 11 euro's (minimal order 50 pieces) each. Albert

Comment: I haven't gotten as far as PIN verification, but 2 things you can try. First, maybe you need to verify the pin first and then do the update command, and in the update APDU only specify the new PIN code. It seems you are currently sending both the old PIN and the new one. Secondly, maybe the second parameter is incorrect. According to - www.smart-cards.ru/upload/catalog/items/docs/doc0225.pdf - it should be 0xD2. Also in the example the fourth parameter is 1, so the APDU looks like FF,D2,00,01,03,01,02,03 (new pin = 1,2,3). Let me know how this works.

Comment: I can buy 1021 at ~6 euros a piece, but 3021 cost ~20 euros a piece (minimum amount 10). Although most of the studios that use my app have 3021s and I could probably persuade the bosses to replace the few 1021s still in use, we don't have the money to replace all the backup card readers, which happen to be 1021s. So I need to get this new code working with 1021 as well...

Comment: Hello Marko,

FF,D2,00,01,03,01,02,03 (new pin = 1,2,3) does not work (also after verifying existing PIN:
6D,00,FF,20,00,00 03,FF,FF,FF) - It returns error code 6D00.
For us (yet) not a huge problem, as we code our cards now with the Xiring XiMax terminals (stand-alone terninals

Answer (score 0):

FF,D2,00,01,03,01,02,03 (new pin = 1,2,3) does not work (also after verifying existing PIN:
6D,00,FF,20,00,00 03,FF,FF,FF) - It returns error code 6D00.

For us (yet) not a huge problem, as we code our cards now with the Xiring XiMax terminal (programmable terminal with it's own SDK, the terminal can store data in flash memory).
However, we need to find a solution soon. I am interested in your (future) findings.
Do you have the Omnikey SDK? We can send you working examples in C++ that can change PSC (pin) and data on SLE4442/5542 cards.

This week (so not tomorrow, as previously stated, we have many things going on and are constantly ) we will test the (so far) working code with the Omnikey 1021). Hope to help you out.

We always have 50+ Omnikey 3121 readers on stock and we can offer you these (1+) for a far batter price. Let me know if you are interested.
I am also interested what where you are located and what applications you are developing.

Comment: I fiddled around with changing the PIN. I tried all combinations, the one you wrote first and the one I provided, but I got the same result - 6D00. Then I simply messed around (trial and error) with the INS parameter (0x24) and by pure luck, I think I found the correct APDU - 0xFF,0x21,0,0,6,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,1,2,3 (new pin = 1,2,3; 0x stands for hex values). This apdu responded with 0x90,0x00 and the previous verify command stopped working. After changing the pin value in the verify command to the new pin, did it start working again. :)

Comment: Great Marko,this is it! Thank you for your help. For our Loyalty system -up till now- we used standalone programmable terminals (from Xiring; > 85 euro) with 1 MB flash memory. Now can use the Omnikey in combination with PC and thus offer far better prices. If we can be of any help, let me know. Today we will look into the 1021 reader. I will keep you informed. Thanks again, Albert

Comment: Marko,I just found out that we have OMNIKEY 3121 and 3021 (costs less than 10 euro). Both work with mentioned APDU's.

Comment: What are your results with the 1021 reader? I've been talking to Omnikey support about this matter, their main response seems to always be to use their syncrhonous API (because the APDUs are unsupported), but they don't seem te get it through their thick skulls that the API is only 32bit and I can't load 32bit dll's in a 64bit application. I also found a bug in their driver that can BSOD a machine, they said they would fix it, but god knows when (couldn't promise a new version this year). I urged them to also fix the write APDU with 1021, but they were very vague about that as well...