# Read write data in SLE4442 smart card with java commandAPDU?

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu

I want to read and write data in SLE4442 smart card 
i have ACR38U-i1 smart card reader

For write I am use this commandAPDU

```
byte[] cmdApduPutCardUid = new byte[]{(byte)0xFF, (byte)0xD0,  (byte)0x40,(byte)0x00,  (byte)4,(byte)6,(byte)2,(byte)6,(byte)2};
```

And for read data

```
byte[] cmdApduGetCardUid = new byte[]{(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xB0,(byte)0x40,(byte)0x00,(byte)0xFF};
```

both are execute  and send SW= 9000 
but no one data receive in responseAPDU 
Like I write 6262 data but it not receive

I am also use Select command to before write and read command

The select command is

```
byte[] cmdApduSlcCardUid = new byte[]{(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xA4,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x06};
```

Have anyone Proper java code to read and write  in SLE4442 smart card ?

Comment: because  Command of APDU are same java and c++

Comment: Bo perssone are you already work with smart cards in any language

Comment: @BoPersson no i am not work with smart card its my first time have any Solution than help me in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APDU Commands related to work with Memory Cards could be different for different readers and implemented support. Here is an [example for OmniKey reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250905/read-write-sle4442-memory-card-with-winscard-api-in-c-sharp/3594029#3594029).

Take a look to your [ACR reader specification](http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/PMA_ACR38x(CCID)_v6.01.pdf) and use specific Pseudo-APDU command to work with SLE 4442.

For your question:

4.6.1 **SELECT_CARD_TYPE**: `"FF A4 00 00 01 06"`, where `0x06` in the data meant *"Infineon SLE 4432 and SLE 4442"*.

4.6.2 **READ_MEMORY_CARD**: `"FF B0 00 [Bytes Address] [MEM_L]"`, where

- `[Bytes Address]`: is the memory address location of memory card
- `[MEM_L]`: Length of data to be read from the memory card

4.6.5 **WRITE_MEMORY_CARD**: `"FF D0 00 [Bytes Address] [MEM_L] [Data]"`

- `[Data]`: data to be written to the memory card

You used `P1 = 0x40` and this could be an issue.

Comment: i am also use this for write data in SLE 4442 card use ACR reader writer but not successful in write data inside card have any full code which is help first write digit like 123 and then read these digit successfully     I am try this from last year so please help me

Comment: Hello one thing more if we work with this card we need pin or not

Comment: @BoPersson if we work with this card we need pin or not and if you have  full code of java then please provide me i am try from last year but no solution found

Comment: @Michael Roland Please help me this Topic i am working throw last year but not resolve

Comment: @RubyBhullar did you a found solution how to write into SLE 4442 cart with ACR Reader?

Comment: @Capripio actually i don't find the good way of write because R/W and Empty Card not available essaily So my work is pending

Comment: @RubyBhullar it turns out you need to authenticate before you can write into a card. try to use this command FF 20 00 00 03 FF FF FF (last 6 FF is for default pin) and then try to write its worked fine for me!

Comment: @Capripio thanks for valuable answer i am try your code tomorrow and also tell you the overall result