# Make SLE 5542 Smart Cards Read Only After Binary Write Using APDU

Tags: c#, smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard

Excited to ask my first question over here... so here goes..

I am Currently working with the Composite Smart Cards (one with both the NFC MIFARE 1k And Chip Encode ) SLE 5542,

So far i have  managed to perform the following task with the MIFARE

1. Read write of values in Blocks of the sector
2. changing the access bits and  authentication key A and B for the sector trails so as manage the access control of the sector of the block in which i have written so that i can make my values read only.

As for the Chip Encode i have managed to .

Performing read write in the Contact Chip using READ BINARY AND WRITE BINARY APDU commands.

But Now i am stuck in the process of making the values written in the chip to be readonly ,

I found a [document](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/6009/TDS_SLE5542.pdf) over the internet in which under the Circuit Description it is telling about the need of PSC And Protection Memory for the read protection of the Data Memory

But can not find the exact APDU Commands and the right way of the read write protection of the data memory.

P.S Let me know if you need any further clarifications

Comment: Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850578/read-write-data-in-sle4442-smart-card-with-java-commandapdu/32887532#32887532)

Comment: guidot ,I have already seen the link before which is for the read and write of memory , i have already performed the read and write process on the card , now i want to lock my card so that no other can perform the read write on my values..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory cards like SLE55xx don't understand APDUs - and I lost count, how often this was asked here already. Most readers capable of handling these cards offer a translation service to make addressing via PCSC easier, but then you have to look at the reader's documentation. Since you specified neither the reader nor the API apparently successfully used, there is not much else to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but i managed to lock the card ,  i used the the Omni Key Sync API to perform read write and changing the pin of the card , i looked in the documentation for and found a simple command to change the PIN code of the card,

Since SLE5542 are composite card , consisting of both MIFARE 1k and PC /SC Microprocessor chip. I used APDU Commands to Perform Read Write values for the mifare , where as for the PC /sc chip I used the HID Omni Key Sync API Manage the Chip card